# VBA Macro to Extract Outlook Attachment Excel Data and Paste into Specific Worksheet Cells

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I believe I have finally spliced a VBA code together in order to do what I'm trying to accomplish however I can't seem to get the specifics correct.

Scenario - I receive 3 emails every night at 8pm that contain 1 excel/csv attachment each.  I would like this code to sweep the emails and extract data from each attachment, taking a specified Range from each attachment and paste that data into 3 separate specific Ranges within an external locally saved master excel worksheet.

My details that I still need to input:

AttachmentTitles(1) = "Queue Status - Collections.csv"

AttachmentTitles(2) = "KPI Collections - Inbound.csv"

AttachmentTitles(3) = "KPI Collections - Outbound.csv"

' Copy the data from the Excel attachment

```
 "Queue Status - Collections.csv" - Range = "A2:S12"
 "KPI Collections - Inbound.csv" - Range = "H2:X12"
 "KPI Collections - Outbound.csv" - Range = "H2:X12"
```

' Set the range where you want to paste the extracted data

```
 "Queue Status - Collections.csv" - Range = "A2:S12" data should always paste into the next available Row in "Collections Master Workbook.xlsx"

 "KPI Collections - Inbound.csv" - Range = "H2:X12" data should always paste into the 20th column of the same available Row as previous

 "KPI Collections - Outbound.csv" - Range = "H2:X12" data should always paste into the 37th column of the same available Row as previous
```

' Specify the Outlook folder where the email is located

```
 Inbox.Projects.Collections.Daily Reports     -     It's a sub-sub-subfolder if that makes sense?
```

So ultimately there should always be a total 11 Rows and 53 Columns of data pasted into "Collections Master Workbook.xlsx" - that's the final goal

Thank you so much for your help, and if I need a path for the "Collections Master Workbook.xlsx" please just let me know.

Here is what I have so far as a template:

---

```
Sub ExtractDataFromOutlookEmail()
    
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    
    Dim OutlookNamespace As Object
    
    Dim OutlookFolder As Object
    
    Dim OutlookItem As Object
    
    Dim ExcelApp As Object
    
    Dim ExcelWorkbook As Object
    
    Dim ExcelWorksheet As Object
    
    Dim Attachment As Object
    
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    
    Dim TempFileName As String
    
    Dim RangeToExtract As Range
    
    ' Set the path where you want to save the extracted data
    
    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & ""
    
    ' Set the range where you want to paste the extracted data
    
    Set RangeToExtract = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") ' Change to your desired range
    
    ' Create a new Outlook application
    
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    ' Specify the Outlook folder where the email is located
    
    Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    Set OutlookFolder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) ' Change to the appropriate folder
    
    ' Loop through the emails in the folder
    
    For Each OutlookItem In OutlookFolder.Items
        
        ' Check if the email has the desired attachments
        
        If OutlookItem.Attachments.Count >= 1 Then
            
            ' Check if the attachments have specific titles
            
            Dim AttachmentTitles(1 To 3) As String
            
            AttachmentTitles(1) = "Attachment1.xlsx" ' Replace with the title of the first attachment
            
            AttachmentTitles(2) = "Attachment2.xlsx" ' Replace with the title of the second attachment
            
            AttachmentTitles(3) = "Attachment3.xlsx" ' Replace with the title of the third attachment
            
            Dim AttachmentCount As Integer
            
            AttachmentCount = 0
            
            ' Loop through the attachments in the email
            
            For Each Attachment In OutlookItem.Attachments
                
                For i = 1 To 3
                    
                    If Attachment.Filename = AttachmentTitles(i) Then
                        
                        ' Save the attachment to the temporary location
                        
                        Attachment.SaveAsFile TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(i)
                        
                        ' Create a new Excel application
                        
                        Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
                        
                        ExcelApp.Visible = False
                        
                        ' Open the saved Excel attachment
                        
                        Set ExcelWorkbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(i))
                        
                        ' Copy the data from the Excel attachment
                        
                        Set ExcelWorksheet = ExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1) ' Assuming data is in the first sheet
                        
                        ExcelWorksheet.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=RangeToExtract.Offset(, AttachmentCount * 3) ' Offset to paste data in different columns
                        
                        ' Close the Excel attachment
                        
                        ExcelWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
                        
                        ExcelApp.Quit
                        
                        ' Clean up Excel objects
                        
                        Set ExcelWorksheet = Nothing
                        
                        Set ExcelWorkbook = Nothing
                        
                        Set ExcelApp = Nothing
                        
                        ' Increment the attachment count
                        
                        AttachmentCount = AttachmentCount + 1
                        
                        ' Exit the loop if all three attachments are processed
                        
                        If AttachmentCount >= 3 Then Exit For
                        
                    End If
                    
                Next i
                
            Next Attachment
            
            ' Exit the loop after processing the email
            
            Exit For
            
        End If
        
    Next OutlookItem
    
    ' Clean up Outlook objects
    
    Set OutlookItem = Nothing
    
    Set OutlookFolder = Nothing
    
    Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
    
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    
    ' Delete the temporary Excel files
    
    For i = 1 To 3
        
        If Dir(TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(i)) <> "" Then
            
            Kill TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(i)
            
        End If
        
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

I have tried multiple combinations with no success. The first error I come across is it gives me a conmpile error: user-defined type not defined and then it highlights the Dim RangeToExtract As Range line at the top?

Comment: What host application are you running this in?

Comment: It will be ran in outlook unless there's a better way? Ultimately I would like it to run at a certain time each day as well automatically.

Comment: If you're running it in outlook, then you need a reference to the Excel object library under Tools > References for `As Range`.

Comment: That seemed to work however now I have input my specifics into the template and when I hit run nothing seems to happen.  Except when I try to open the worksheet that all the data is supposed to paste into it's says it's locked and read only. Been stuck that way for 30 min. Maybe the code isn't ending? Or it's stuck in a loop? The read only worksheet shows blank as well. Even with outlook closed the worksheet says it's in use and read only. It's like permanently locked? Appreciate your help I'm obviously way over my head on this one

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` is used. Code must be in Excel. Since in Excel drop `Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`.

Comment: You can keep late binding to Outlook if you replace `Set OutlookFolder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)` with `Set OutlookFolder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6)`  [OlDefaultFolders enumeration (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.oldefaultfolders)

Comment: Wow this is great. It's working in excel except each incremental attachment is writing over the previous within the workbook. How do I take each attachments copied data and offset them to be pasted in the next available column?

Comment: ' Set the range where you want to paste the extracted data
"Queue Status - Collections.csv" - Copied Range = "A2:S12" data should always paste into the next available Row in "Collections Master Workbook.xlsx"
"KPI Collections - Inbound.csv" - Copied Range = "H2:X12" data should always paste into the 20th column of the same available Row as previous
"KPI Collections - Outbound.csv" - Copied Range = "H2:X12" data should always paste into the 37th column of the same available Row as previous

Comment: @MichaelLawler Re: It's working in excel except each incremental attachment is writing over the previous within the workbook. If you have updated code, edit the question. If less confusing to post a new question, you could try to make it standalone, so there is no need for possible responders to read this post.

Answer (score 0):

Code in "Collections Master Workbook.xlsx".

`ExcelApp` dropped.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExtractDataFromOutlookEmail()
    
    ' Late binding. Outlook variables declared as Object.
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim OutlookNamespace As Object
    Dim OutlookFolder As Object
    Dim OutlookItem As Object
    Dim Attachment As Object
    
    Dim ExcelWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim ExcelWorksheet As Worksheet
    
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    
    Dim RangeToExtract As Range
    
    ' Set the path where you want to save the extracted data
    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp")
    
    ' Set the range where you want to paste the extracted data
    
    ' **** ThisWorkbook is used - code must be in Excel ****
    Set RangeToExtract = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") ' Change to your desired range
    
    ' Create a new Outlook application
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    ' Specify the Outlook folder where the email is located
    'Set OutlookFolder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) ' Change to the appropriate folder
    
    ' With late binding
    ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.oldefaultfolders
    Set OutlookFolder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6) ' Change to the appropriate folder
    
    'Set OutlookFolder = OutlookNamespace.pickfolder
    
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Loop through the emails in the folder
    For Each OutlookItem In OutlookFolder.Items
    
        'Debug.Print OutlookItem.Subject
        
        If TypeName(OutlookItem) = "MailItem" Then
        
            ' Check if the email has the desired attachments
            
            If OutlookItem.Attachments.Count >= 1 Then
                
                ' Check if the attachments have specific titles
                Dim AttachmentTitles(1 To 3) As String
                AttachmentTitles(1) = "Attachment1.xlsx" ' Replace with the title of the first attachment
                AttachmentTitles(2) = "Attachment2.xlsx" ' Replace with the title of the second attachment
                AttachmentTitles(3) = "Attachment3.xlsx" ' Replace with the title of the third attachment
                
                Dim AttachmentCount As Long
                AttachmentCount = 0
                
                ' Loop through the attachments in the email
                
                Dim i As Long
                For Each Attachment In OutlookItem.Attachments
                    
                    For i = 1 To 3
                        
                        If Attachment.Filename = AttachmentTitles(i) Then
                            
                            ' Save the attachment to the temporary location
                            Attachment.SaveAsFile TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(i)
                            
                            ' Open the saved Excel attachment
                            Set ExcelWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(i))
                            
                            ' Copy the data from the Excel attachment
                            Set ExcelWorksheet = ExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1) ' Assuming data is in the first sheet
                            
                            ExcelWorksheet.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=RangeToExtract.Offset(, AttachmentCount * 3) ' Offset to paste data in different columns
                            
                            ' Close the Excel attachment
                            ExcelWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
                            
                            ' Clean up Excel objects
                            Set ExcelWorksheet = Nothing
                            Set ExcelWorkbook = Nothing
                            
                            ' Increment the attachment count
                            AttachmentCount = AttachmentCount + 1
                            
                            ' Exit the loop if all three attachments are processed
                            If AttachmentCount >= 3 Then Exit For
                            
                        End If
                        
                    Next i
                    
                Next Attachment
                
            End If
        
        End If
        
    Next OutlookItem
    
    ' Clean up Outlook objects
    Set OutlookItem = Nothing
    Set OutlookFolder = Nothing
    Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    
    ' Delete the temporary Excel files
    For i = 1 To 3
        If Dir(TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(i)) <> "" Then
            Kill TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(i)
        End If
    Next i
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

If you want the code in Outlook, `ExcelApp` is applicable but not `OutlookApp`.

Open "Collections Master Workbook.xlsx". Replace `ThisWorkbook`.

Answer (score 0):

### I figured out with your help a macro that does exactly what I need it to do. I'm going to start a new standalone thread for some additional help. But here is the working code for anyone interested. Thanks for all your help

Option Explicit

Sub ExtractDataFromOutlookEmail()

```
' Late binding. Outlook variables declared as Object.
Dim OutlookApp As Object
Dim OutlookNamespace As Object
Dim OutlookFolder As Object
Dim OutlookItem As Object
Dim Attachment As Object

Dim ExcelWorkbook As Workbook
Dim ExcelWorksheet As Worksheet

Dim TempFilePath As String

Dim RangeToExtract As Range
Dim RangeToCopy As Range

' Set the path where you want to save the extracted data
TempFilePath = Environ$("temp")

' Set the range where you want to paste the extracted data

' **** ThisWorkbook is used - code must be in Excel ****
Set RangeToExtract = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) ' Change to your desired range

' Create a new Outlook application
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

' Specify the Outlook folder where the email is located
'Set OutlookFolder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) ' Change to the appropriate folder

' With late binding
Set OutlookFolder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6) ' Change to the appropriate folder

'Set OutlookFolder = OutlookNamespace.pickfolder

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Loop through the emails in the folder
For Each OutlookItem In OutlookFolder.Items

    'Debug.Print OutlookItem.Subject
   
    If TypeName(OutlookItem) = "MailItem" Then
   
        ' Check if the email has the desired attachments
       
        If OutlookItem.Attachments.Count >= 1 Then
           
            ' Check if the attachments have specific titles
            Dim AttachmentTitles(1 To 3) As String
            AttachmentTitles(1) = "Queue Status - Collections.csv" ' Replace with the title of the first attachment
            AttachmentTitles(2) = "KPI Collections - Inbound.csv" ' Replace with the title of the second attachment
            AttachmentTitles(3) = "KPI Collections - Outbound.csv" ' Replace with the title of the third attachment
           
            Dim AttachmentCount As Long
            AttachmentCount = 0
           
            ' Loop through the attachments in the email
           
            
            For Each Attachment In OutlookItem.Attachments
                
                
                    
                    If Attachment.Filename = AttachmentTitles(1) Then
                       
                        ' Save the attachment to the temporary location
                        Attachment.SaveAsFile TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(1)
                       
                        ' Open the saved Excel attachment
                        Set ExcelWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(1))
                        
                        ' Copy the data from the Excel attachment
                        Set RangeToCopy = ExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:S12") ' Assuming data is in the first sheet
                       
                        RangeToCopy.Copy Destination:=RangeToExtract.Offset ' Offset to paste data in different columns
                       
                        ' Close the Excel attachment
                        ExcelWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
                       
                        ' Clean up Excel objects
                        Set ExcelWorksheet = Nothing
                        Set ExcelWorkbook = Nothing
                       
                        ' Increment the attachment count
                        AttachmentCount = AttachmentCount + 1
                       
                        ' Exit the loop if all three attachments are processed
                        If AttachmentCount >= 3 Then Exit For
                       
                    End If
                   
                
                
            Next Attachment
           
            For Each Attachment In OutlookItem.Attachments
           
                    If Attachment.Filename = AttachmentTitles(2) Then
                       
                        ' Save the attachment to the temporary location
                        Attachment.SaveAsFile TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(2)
                       
                        ' Open the saved Excel attachment
                        Set ExcelWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(2))
                       
                        ' Copy the data from the Excel attachment
                        Set RangeToCopy = ExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("H2:X12") ' Assuming data is in the first sheet
                       
                        RangeToCopy.Copy Destination:=RangeToExtract.Offset(, 19) ' Offset to paste data in different columns
                       
                        ' Close the Excel attachment
                        ExcelWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
                       
                        ' Clean up Excel objects
                        Set ExcelWorksheet = Nothing
                        Set ExcelWorkbook = Nothing
                       
                        ' Increment the attachment count
                        AttachmentCount = AttachmentCount + 1
                       
                        ' Exit the loop if all three attachments are processed
                        If AttachmentCount >= 3 Then Exit For
                       
                    End If
                   
                
                
            Next Attachment
           
            For Each Attachment In OutlookItem.Attachments
           
                    If Attachment.Filename = AttachmentTitles(3) Then
                       
                        ' Save the attachment to the temporary location
                        Attachment.SaveAsFile TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(3)
                       
                        ' Open the saved Excel attachment
                        Set ExcelWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(3))
                       
                        ' Copy the data from the Excel attachment
                        Set RangeToCopy = ExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("H2:X12") ' Assuming data is in the first sheet
                       
                        RangeToCopy.Copy Destination:=RangeToExtract.Offset(, 36) ' Offset to paste data in different columns
                       
                        ' Close the Excel attachment
                        ExcelWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
                        
                        ' Clean up Excel objects
                        Set ExcelWorksheet = Nothing
                        Set ExcelWorkbook = Nothing
                       
                        ' Increment the attachment count
                        AttachmentCount = AttachmentCount + 1
                       
                        ' Exit the loop if all three attachments are processed
                        If AttachmentCount >= 3 Then Exit For
                       
                    End If
                   
                
                
            Next Attachment
           
        End If
   
    End If
   
Next OutlookItem

' Clean up Outlook objects
Set OutlookItem = Nothing
Set OutlookFolder = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing

' Delete the temporary Excel files

    If Dir(TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(1)) <> "" Then
        Kill TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(1)
    End If
   
    If Dir(TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(2)) <> "" Then
        Kill TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(2)
    End If
   
    If Dir(TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(3)) <> "" Then
        Kill TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(3)
    End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub